# как скопировать часть массива c++

Tags: c++, строки

Всем привет Нужна помощь задача такая
Юзер вводит строку с таким знаком  _ и ее нужно разделить
Пример
user_harry
А вывести
user
harry
Это я сделала но проблемка в Другом как я понимаю Нооо не могу понять в чём .Нужно эти два слова разделённые тобишь user   harry переписать в два массива .И что ? Помогите  .Помощь с кодом не нужна

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
     
    string user;

    cout << "-> " << endl;
    cin >> user;
     int len = user.length();
    int myIndex;
    string mssUser[len], priceTovar[len], nameTovar[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        mssUser[i] = user[i];
         
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (mssUser[i] == "_") {
            myIndex = i;
        }
    }
 /*
    for (int i = 0; i < myIndex; i++)
    {
        mssUser[i] = priceTovar[i];     

    }
    for (int i = myIndex; i < len; i++)
    {
         mssUser[i] = nameTovar[i];

    }
    */  
    /*2+2=4
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
           if (myIndex <=nameTovar)
            {
               mssUser[i] = nameTovar[i];
           }

           else
           {
                mssUser[i] = priceTovar[i];
            }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myIndex; i++)
    {
        cout << nameTovar[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = myIndex; i < len; i++)
    {
        cout << priceTovar[i];
 
    }
 
 }
```

Comment: Формализуем вопрос... У вас есть строка `xxxxxx_yyyyyyy`, на выходе надо получить две строки - `xxxxxx` и `yyyyyyy`? каждая в своей переменной `string`. Я верно понял вашу проблему? Если да - что делать, если 1. подчерков нет вовсе; 2. подчерков больше одного?

Comment: используйте getline и оператор+=

Comment: @Harry
Да   на выходе надо получить две строки а потом эти две строки и переписать в два разных массива .Например вся строка записалась в массив 1 а потом её нужно разделить и первую часть строки переписать в массив 2 а вторую часть в массив 3 .Вот и почему у меня возникли сложности

Comment: По-моему, вы неверно понимаете, что такое `string`... Иначе зачем вы создаете массивы строк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [примерное решение](https://ideone.com/qnrwmO) вашей задачи...

```
int main()
{
    string user;
    cout << "-> ";
    cin >> user;
    string a, b;
    if (size_t pos = user.find('_'); pos != user.npos)
    {
        a = user.substr(0,pos);
        b = user.substr(pos+1);

        cout << a << "\n" << b;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No _ in input\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное